# How to Speed up Test Results show up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit, specflow

I am using Specflow 2.1, Nunitt 3.8.1 and Visual Studio, When I execute the Test the Test Executes but It takes nearly 8 mins to show pass or Fail in Test Explorer until that it keeps loading. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: A long running test? How can we know if don't show us any code?

Comment: Are you using thread.sleeps? Do you have any loops which can go on for a while? No idea without seeing the code first

Comment: It is only at execution of also at discovery of the tests?

Comment: @Alex, It is not execution, but after execution it takes time to show results. In Visual Studio Test Explorer as we know it will show either test is pass or fail. if passes it shows green mark, if fails red cross mark.

So once the execution is done, it keeps loading for 7 to 8 minutes in Test Explorer. then it shows either pass or fail.

AndreasWillich It is only after execution not the discovery discovery happens quickly

Anand I am not using any sleeps in my tests. as I told test execution is not a problem here. problem is after execution to show pass or fail